# scala play json reads for a seal trait or enum type object

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have the following scala code with sealed traits and case objects.

```
sealed trait StudentType {
  val studentLevel: String
  val code: Int
}

case object UnderGradFull extends StudentType {
  val studentLevel = "UGF"
  val code = 11
}
case object UnderGradPart extends StudentType {
  val studentLevel = "UGP"
  val code = 12
}
case object Grad extends StudentType {
  val studentLevel = "GR"
  val code = 22
}
case object OtherStudentType extends StudentType {
  val studentLevel = "OST"
  val code = 20
}
```

and case class object that makes use of `StudentType`

```
case class StudentInfo(studentName: String, studentType: StudentType)

object StudentInfo {
  implicit val reads: Reads[StudentInfo] = (
    (JsPath \ "studentName").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "studentType").read[StudentType]
  )(StudentInfo.apply _)

  implicit val writes: Writes[StudentInfo] = (
    (JsPath \ "studentName").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "studentType").write[StudentType]
  )(unlift(StudentInfo.unapply))
}
```

how can I create `implicit reads/writes` for the `StudentType trait`?

Comment: The macro for automated reads/writes supports wellformed sealed trait/family.

Answer (score 4):

`play-json` seems to have out-of-the-box support for sealed traits. Analysing

- [pull request that introduced the feature](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/16)
- [other pull requests around sealed traits](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aclosed%20Support%20sealed)
- [tests that show usage](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/json/code/ScalaJsonAutomatedSpec.scala)
- [docs](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/json/ScalaJsonAutomated.md)

it seems the way to use it is as follows

```
sealed trait Family
case class ChildA(status: Boolean) extends Family
case class ChildB(name: String, age: Int) extends Family

implicit val childAFormat = Json.format[ChildA]
implicit val childBFormat = Json.format[ChildB]
implicit val familyFormat = Json.format[Family]

println(
  Json.parse(
    """{
      |  "name": "Bob",
      |  "age": 10,
      |  "_type": "controllers.ChildB"
      |}""".stripMargin
  ).as[Family]
)
```

which prints out `ChildB(Bob,10)`.

[`play-json-extensions`](https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions#automatic-formatting-of-sealed-traits-delegating-to-formatters-of-the-subclasses) also seems to support sealed traits like so

```
sealed trait Family
case class ChildA(status: Boolean) extends Family
case class ChildB(name: String, age: Int) extends Family

implicit val childBFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[ChildB]
implicit val childAFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[ChildA]
implicit val familyFormat = Jsonx.formatSealed[Family]

println(
  Json.parse(
    """{
      |  "name": "Bob",
      |  "age": 10
      |}""".stripMargin
  ).as[Family]
)
```

which prints out `ChildB(Bob,10)`.

Regarding case objects I was only able to get it working when they are empty

```
sealed trait Family
case object ChildA extends Family
case object ChildB extends Family

implicit val childAFormat = Json.format[ChildA.type]
implicit val childBFormat = Json.format[ChildB.type]
implicit val familyFormat = Json.format[Family]
```

so I am not sure how to solve your question exactly, however hopefully this answer gives some direction.